# Prompt user without waiting

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a long running process, coded in "R". I would like to continue running it in RStudio, I don't want to use batch mode.

I would like to allow the user to gracefully terminate the long running process, for example by pressing the escape key. If the user doesn't press anything, the process continues, without waiting.

I have read other StackOverflow posts, perhaps I need to prompt the user using scan/readline on a different thread. That way, the main execution thread isn't blocked.

Isn't there a simpler way?

Thank you for any pointers/suggestions.

Richard Rogers

---

Further comments:

I've made a few mistakes:

1. I didn't realize that pressing escape in RStudio while the code is
       running halts execution.
2. I can't seem to determine where execution ends when I press escape.
3. Maybe I can use a simpler question.

Here is a simple function:

```
ProcessData <- function()
{
    Continue <- TRUE
    Iteration <- 1

    TestData <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 100000)

    while (Continue)
    {
        writeLines(sprintf("Processing iteration %d, Current time is %s", Iteration, Sys.time()))
        process.events()

        TestData <- round(runif(100000, min = 1, max = 10))
        # Continue <- PromptUser()

        Iteration <- Iteration + 1
    }

    writeLines("Processing ending.")
    head(TestData)
}
```

If I press escape while the loop is running, the writeLines and head calls don't get executed. How can I ensure that they do?

Thank you again,

Richard

Comment: Is your process supposed to run in the background somehow?

Comment: Unless you're doing any kind of multiple R process handling I think `ESC` is the functionality you'll be limited to.  R uses an interactive paradigm so if you're trying to avoid starting two processes, one to manage the other, I think that a regular user interrupt like that is the only way.

Comment: Though not a trivial example, [`opencpu`](http://opencpu.org) ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/opencpu/index.html)) starts a separate *R* process in the background but allows the user to continue coding as well as stop/restart it. In that (development) mode, it is not intended to be run in batch-mode (it has a much more robust model for production environments). There's a lot of source to read through, but it can be done. (Sorry I can't offer a "include these lines of code".)

Comment: Short of that, writing your code so that it saves state frequently enough and can be interrupted/continued (if needed) may be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but since I had a similar context (long-running task), here is what I came up with:

```
long_computation <- function() for(i in 1:10) Sys.sleep(1) 
exit_gracefully <- function() cat("Saving results so far...\n")
tryCatch(
    long_computation(),  
    finally = exit_gracefully()
)
```

If we press escape during the computation, no error condition seems to be thrown; however the `finally` part of `tryCatch` gets executed. This allows us to clean up, close connections etc.