# Best method to stop a (parallel) loop in R & restart it where it stopped

Tags: r, rstudio

## Background

So here is my plan: Sometimes I want to run loops that take a long time to complete but I also don't have a dedicated machine to run these analyses on because I need to use the computer for other stuff as well (e.g. during the day). So what am I looking for is a neat way to start, pause and restart the loop and making it relatively robust (against my idiocy).

What I **want**:

- I think given the hassle that I save in most cases it would be fine for me to restart at i - 1 if i is the time point where I stopped the loop.
- I might have some idea how to make it work for standard for-loop but no idea how to do this for parallel code but I think it would  be very useful.
- Make it robust and only require a limited sequence of specific user input.

What I **don't want**:

- Tell the loop for how long to run this time. It would defeat the purpose if I had to tell the loop: now you have 24 hours to run and then I want to use the computer. I want to be able to stop & start it manually.

## Idea

One way could be to check whether a file exists that is automatically saved and includes our index and has saved the progress but I am unsure what the best way is to implement this.

Here is my current code:

```
# Large number of iteration
iter     <- 1e5
some_var <- rep(NA, iter)

# Use this value for the first time
i <- 1

# Set startIndex
startIndex <- i

# Loop that takes a long time to run
for(i in startIndex:iter){
  # Sleep
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # Do something with i
  cat(paste0("\r ", i))
  
  # Save something
  some_var[i] <- i
}
```

When the loop is running in RStudio I can simply press **ESC** on my windows keyboard and the loop is interrupted. The whole things starts from where it stopped by running the code from `# Set startIndex`.

However, this still relies me on always carrying out running the sections of code in a specific order and I am wondering whether there are extra tricks that I can use to avoid this.

## Edit: Parallel version of the problem

The parallel code doesn't have to use these packages...

```
# Parallel version
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

# Large number of iteration
nIter     <- 1e5

# Create the cluster following https://www.blasbenito.com/post/02_parallelizing_loops_with_r/
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(detectCores() - 2, type = "PSOCK")

#register it to be used by %dopar%
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)

# To start from here
startIndex <- 1

# Parallel loop
some_var <- foreach(i = startIndex:nIter, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  # Sleep
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # Do something with i (I know cat is a bad exmaple because it won't be printed)
  cat(paste0("\r ", i))
  
  # Save something
  return(i)
}

# Stop cluster again
parallel::stopCluster(cl = my.cluster)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution that takes an idea from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761205/prompt-user-without-waiting). It embeds the loop in a `tryCatch` to exit it gracefully after interruption, saving the actual state. The next run then checks existence of an image dump and continues with the next index (or one less if you want).

```r
# see also
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761205/prompt-user-without-waiting

exit_gracefully <- function() {
  cat("Saving results so far...\n")
  cat("start   index =", startIndex, "\n")
  cat("current index =", i, "\n")
  save.image("image_dump.rda")
}

# Large number of iteration
iter     <- 1e5
some_var <- rep(NA, iter)

# Use this value for the first time
i <- 1

# Set startIndex
startIndex <- i

if (file.exists("image_dump.rda")) {
  load("image_dump.rda")
  startIndex <- i - 1
}

# Loop that takes a long time to run
tryCatch(
  for(i in startIndex:iter){
    # Sleep
    Sys.sleep(1)

    # Do something with i
    cat(paste0("\r ", i))

    # Save something
    some_var[i] <- i
  },
  finally = exit_gracefully()
)

exit_gracefully()
```

To extend this to parallel execution, a parallelized example would be helpful. Which operating system and parallelization package will be used?

Comment: Amazing! This is really perfect for me. The previous post (probably because of the title) didn't come up for me. I use Windows 10 and often `foreach` and `doParallel` but I am not married to any of them.